# Правильно ли я разделил задачи между функциями и как упростить код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, инспекция-кода

Код, который может выполнять две задачи:

0 - печатать последние сообщения и
1 - показать 200 сообщений из диалога.

Код работает, но в плане читабельности и костыльности я провалился.
Может лучше класс применять? Правильно ли я разделил задачи между функциями?
Правильная ли у меня архитектура?

```
import vk
from datetime import datetime
import time
import json
import constants # здесь находятся токен и ид пользователя (спец. скрыл, чтоб не узнали)


def auth(): #аутентификация
    access_token = constants.TOKEN
    session = vk.Session(access_token=access_token)
    api = vk.API(session)
    return api

def check_id(api, peer_id): # Кто это? пользователь или группа, узнать имю и фамилию
    if int(peer_id)<0:
        return "Group"
    else:
        time.sleep(0.5) 
        name = api.users.get(user_id = peer_id, fields = "nickname", v="5.80")[0]
        print(name)
        first_name = name['first_name']
        last_name = name['last_name']
        return "{0} {1}".format(first_name, last_name)
def get_Attachments(message, date, dict_ids): #есть ли прикрепления(фото, аудио, документы)
    string = """"""
    if 'attachments' in message.keys():            #не нравится мне это
        for attachment in message['attachments']:  # и это. Может в одну строчку?
            user_id = str(message['from_id'])
            if attachment['type'] == "photo":
                photo = attachment['photo']['sizes']
                for i in photo:
                    if i['type'] == "x":url = i['url']
                string += "{0} photo: {1}  {2}\n".format(dict_ids[user_id], url, date)
            elif attachment['type'] == "doc":
                url = attachment['doc']['url']
                string += "{0} photo: {1}  {2}\n".format(dict_ids[user_id], url, date)
            elif attachment['type'] == "audio":
                url = attachment['audio']['url']
                string += "{0} photo: {1}  {2}\n".format(dict_ids[user_id], url, date)
    return string

def see_msg(api, peer_id):
    dict_ids = {}
    string = """"""
    main_id = constants.main_id
    data = api.messages.getHistory(peer_id=peer_id, count=200, v="5.80")['items']
    data.reverse()
    for message in data:
        date = datetime.fromtimestamp(message['date'])
        date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        user_id = str(message['from_id'])
        if user_id not in dict_ids.keys():
            dict_ids[user_id] = check_id(api, user_id)
        string += "{0}: {1}  {2}\n".format(dict_ids[user_id], 
                                         message['text'], date)
        attachments = get_Attachments(message, date, dict_ids)
        string += attachments
    return string
def get_msg(api):
    data = api.messages.get(count=200, v="5.80")['items']
    data.reverse()
    print(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4,  ensure_ascii=False))

def main():
    api = auth()
    while 1: # основной цикл
        s = input("0 - get latest msg,\
                   \n1 - See Dialog")
        if s == "0":
            data = get_msg(api)
        elif s == "1":
            peer_id = input("Enter peer_id : ")
            data = see_msg(api, peer_id)
            print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Понравится ли мой код PEP8?

Comment: используйте pycodestyle pip install pycodestyle

Answer (score 0):

Только какие-то примечания (специально для вашего кода):

- *2 пустые строки* между определением функций (`def`) (PEP 8)
- *не меньше чем 2 пробела* перед инлайн коментарием (PEP 8)
- *пробел перед и за оператором* (PEP 8)
- никаких пробелов перед и за `=` в ключевых параметрах (PEP 8)
- длина строк кода не больше чем 79 символов (PEP 8)
- `get_аttachments` вместо `get_Attachments` (PEP 8)
- `if user_id not in dict_ids:`
  вместо `if user_id not in dict_ids.keys():`
- `while True: # основной цикл` вместо `while 1: # основной цикл`
- Или *все* строчные литерали *в апострофах*, или *все в кавычках*  (PEP 8)